# Why is my dictionary not sorting correctly when summing larger arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I'm currently working on the leetcode question that counts the number of 1's and 0's in a matrix by row and then returns the row with the least amount of leading ones. also there is a variable k which will return the number of rows.

Example:
input is [[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0]], k = 2
output is [1,0]

The way I worked this out in my code is to iterate based on the amount of rows and then add each column, checking if there is a "1" or not. Then after each iteration of columns append to a dictionary the row identifier (i) as the key and the value as count. After that I sort the dictionary by the values and return [0,k] to get the correct number of rows.

Now the problem occurs when it attempted to use a larger matrix, the row identifier and count are appended to the dictionary correctly, but when the sorting command is used it sorts it in a seemingly random order, which then makes it return an incorrect number.

My guess is that I'm not understanding the sort function correctly, but then I'm not sure why it would work on smaller matrices, please let me know if you can spot the problem!

```
def kWeakestRows(mat, k):
    length = len(mat[0])
    rows = len(mat)
    dict = {}
    for i in range (rows):
        count = 0
        for j in range (length):
            if mat[i][j] == 1:
                count += 1
                dict[str(i)] = str(count)
            else:
                dict[str(i)] = str(count)
    dict = sorted(dict, key=dict.get)
    return dict[0:k]

matrix = [[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

k = 4
print(kWeakestRows(matrix, k))
```

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, you're shadowing the built-in class name.

Comment: You don't need to convert the dictionary keys to strings, numbers can be used as keys.

Comment: You're counting all the 1's, not just the leading 1's. If that's what you want, you can simply use `dict[i] = sum(mat[i])`

Comment: To count just the leading 1's, break out of the inner loop in the `else:` block.

Comment: The sorting seems fine, though. Could you give an example where the sort isn't returning what you expect?

Comment: @Barmar In  the example provided above with a k=1, the output I am receiving is [13] when the expected output if the code was working correctly would be [4]

Comment: Is that because of the sorting or because you're not counting correctly? Print the dictionary to see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, when I print the dictionary the results is {'0': '3', '1': '5', '2': '11', '3': '9', '4': '2', '5': '5', '6': '5', '7': '8', '8': '16', '9': '5', '10': '8', '11': '9', '12': '14', '13': '10', '14': '15', '15': '15', '16': '3'}.

after sorted the result becomes. ['13', '2', '12', '14', '15', '8', '4', '0', '16', '1', '5', '6', '9', '7', '10', '3', '11']

Comment: @Barmar After relooking at the results I realize what is happening... It is sorting by then tens place first and then the ones place, ie: 11, 12, 16, 17, 2, 3, 4, 5. Following your advice to not convert the int's to strings allowed the code to work correctly. Thank you!